# How to render component (optionsmenu) in special table row, when show options button was clicked

Tags: reactjs

So i have dynamicaly rendered table with rows and data, that i'm getting from db. Every row in table has special button 'ShowOptions'. In that td element i want to render component OptionsMenu, if that button was clicked. But i cant understand logic how to do that?

OptionsMenu component is the same for every table row, with same options, but different id as a params on option functions. I cant understand how to render component in special place (td for special row) if i need it. Please help! Here is example of code

This is dynamicaly getting data for table.

```
let tableData = ''

    if (this.state.agents) {
      tableData = this.state.agents.map(agent => (
        <tr key={agent.id}>
          <td>
            <UserAvatar size='26' url={agent.avatar} />
          </td>
          <td>
            {agent.lastName + ' ' + agent.name + ' ' + agent.middleName}
            <br />
            <span className='OnlineRowCounter'>Последняя активность: 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>{agent.role}</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>{agent.phone}</td>
          <td>{agent.manager}</td>
          <td>
            <div className='OptionsButton-Container'>
              <IconicButton type='options' clicked icon='list-ul' />
              {/* //Here i want to render component below. If i leave as it is, every row will have this component. Ofcourse i can hide it and show in special row i guess, but is it will be the right solution? */}
              <OptionsMenu options={tableRowOptions}/> 

            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.create a empty array in state.
2.And then when clicked push the selected items into array
3. In Show options onclick add the details you wanted I.e agent
4. Render it based on condition this. State.array.includes(AgentName).
5. Use fragment to render td’s.